# How to get tomcat worker status from jkmanager

Tags: apache, tomcat, worker, mod-jk, ajp

We have 3 `Machines`

1. `mod_jk` with `load balancer`
2. first `Worke`r on `tomcat8`
3. 2nd `Worker` on `tomcat8`

everything works as expected but, when one of the `tomcat` is being shutting down the `status page` on the `load balancer` still shows that the state of this `worker` is `OK/IDLE`.

Any ideas how to force the status page to check the real status of the worker?

#### Related Materials

`worker.properties`

```
\### Define worker names
worker.list=status,loadbalancer

\### Declare Tomcat server 1
worker.worker1.port=8409
worker.worker1.host=centureapp1
worker.worker1.type=ajp13
worker.worker1.lbfactor=1

\### Declare Tomcat server 2
worker.worker2.port=8410
worker.worker2.host=centureapp2
worker.worker2.type=ajp13
worker.worker2.lbfactor=1

worker.loadbalancer.type=lb
worker.loadbalancer.balance_workers=worker1,worker2
worker.loadbalancer.sticky_session=1
worker.status.type=status
~
```

Comment: Hi, I have the similar problem with `jk status manager`, plz help to take a look at my new post here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29641090/jk-status-managerstatus-worker-of-mod-jk1-2-32-doesnt-show-the-correct-state

Comment: hey @DerekY from my understanding you cannot count on this status. It will only get update when the `lb` check the status of the worker and i could not find away to force it to check the status

Answer (score 0):

By default balancer maintenance runs every 60 seconds. So, you will see the state of this worker after 60 seconds.

Comment: hey there, thanks for answering. do you know if there is an option to force the checking of status with some api/call? or less good but still a solution, is it possible to reduce the maintenance time?

Comment: Don't think it's correct, I wait for 60 minutes but the status is still ok, please help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29641090/jk-status-managerstatus-worker-of-mod-jk1-2-32-doesnt-show-the-correct-state