# JK Status Manager(status worker) of mod_jk1.2.32 doesn't show the correct state of worker on the web interface

Tags: java, apache, tomcat, load-balancing, mod-jk

My application is using `Apache`,`mod-jk` and `Tomcat` for load balancing, which works fine with this `work.properties`:

```
worker.list=workerlist
# Set properties for worker3
worker.worker3.type=ajp13
worker.worker3.host=xxxx
worker.worker3.port=xx
worker.worker3.lbfactor=4
worker.worker4.ping_mode=A
worker.worker3.socket_timeout=30
worker.worker3.reply_timeout=30000

# Set properties for worker4
worker.worker4.type=ajp13
worker.worker4.host=xxxx
worker.worker4.port=xx
worker.worker4.lbfactor=4
worker.worker4.ping_mode=A
worker.worker4.socket_timeout=30
worker.worker4.reply_timeout=30000

# Set properties for workerlist(lb)
worker.workerlist.type=lb
worker.workerlist.balance_workers=worker4,worker3
worker.workerlist.sticky_session=1

worker.list=jkstatus
worker.jkstatus.type=status
```

What happens is that when I shutdown the `worker4`(Tomcat), the web interface of `JK Status Manager`(http://apachehost/jkstatus) still shows the `worker4` is in `ACT` and `OK/IDLE` State, which makes no sense because the `worker4` is no longer available. And I don't see any error message in the `mod-jk.log`.
[image]

However, when I change the `worker.properties` to have only the unavailable `worker4` and try access again, the page shows the `ERR` Satte:
[image]

The `mod-jk.log` shows:

```
[error] ajp_service::jk_ajp_common.c (2626): (worker4) connecting to tomcat failed.
[info] service::jk_lb_worker.c (1400): service failed, worker worker4 is in error state
[info] service::jk_lb_worker.c (1480): All tomcat instances are busy or in error state
[error] service::jk_lb_worker.c (1485): All tomcat instances failed, no more workers left
```

My questions are:

- According to [Service Availablity Rating](https://tomcat.apache.org/connectors-doc/reference/status.html) on Tomcat's website, it says "**OK (idle): This worker didn't receive any request since the last balancer maintenance. By default balancer maintenance runs every 60 seconds. The worker should be OK, but since we didn't have to use it for some time, we can't be sure. This state has been called N/A before version 1.2.24.**". What I understand from this is mod-jk itself would maintain the connection automatically. So why not the `JK Status Manager` give me alert if one of the worker is down? Does the maintenance not work or the `JK Status Manager` website not work properly?
- Besides `JK Status Manager`, is there other way to monitor the status of workers in real time? I mean if one server is down, I'd like to know immediately.
- Does the `ping_mode` have to be set explicitly?Is it default "A"? The log said that:
  `[warn] jk_map_handle_duplicates::jk_map.c (446): Duplicate key 'worker.worker4.ping_mode' detected - previous value 'A' will be overwritten with 'A'.`

Comment: "Besides JK Status Manager, is there other way to monitor the status of workers in real time? I mean if one server is down, I'd like to know immediately." This what i have search myself. but cloud not find a good way of doing that than speak with each worker individually

Comment: @oak do you finally manage to see the correct state of the worker?

Answer (score 0):

1) If one Tomcat worker fails, nothing is happening until the next check of your balancer. Therefore OK/Idle is displayed. After 60 seconds it should turn into Err state.

2) There are for sure other tools and that page is just an info and not form management. The easiest way would be to set up a servlet, that responses HTTP_200 status. You can check its availability i.e. with an URL object, from an external program.

3) That message is displayed, because you have a typo in your config in line 7 (worker4 instead of worker3):

```
worker.worker4.ping_mode=A
```

Comment: 1) After 60 seconds, the `OK/IDLE` remains, that is the problem of the whole thing.
3) thanks for pointing my typo. My bad~